# Sort list of strings with lambda and ignore prefix

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, lambda

I'm trying to sort a list but ignoring a prefix. This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428835/ignore-characters-during-sort-python). It should be straight forward, only it's not working. Here's what I have:

```
def sort_it(lst, ignore):

  return lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.strip(ignore))

myList = ["cheesewhiz", "www.cheese.com", "www.wagons.com", "www.apples.com", "www.bananas.com"]

ignoreThis = "www."
sort_it(myList, ignoreThis)
print myList
```

Only the sorting is getting mixed up as the first item doesn't have anything to ignore as part of the string. I'm not sure if adding a check to see if the string contains the ignore string is the Pythonic approach with Lambda.

I expect the results to be in alphabetic order ignoring the www.

```
www.apples.com
www.bananas.com
www.cheese.com
cheesewhiz
www.wagons.com
```

Comment: Change from sort to sorted. The sort function changes the list in place; `sorted leaves the original list alone, and returns a copy, sorted.

Comment: Your key function is wrong. `str.strip` isn't suited to remove a prefix. Use `lambda x: x[4:] if x.startswith('www.') else x`.

Comment: @Prune Sure, but that isn't the fundamental problem here.

Comment: The problem is that the strip function is stripping the values only when comparing. It is not affecting actual values in the list.

Comment: @SwakeertJain The problem is that `"www.wagons.com".strip("www.")` returns `'agons.com'`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is also an issue, but I believe a different one than the OP is facing. They want the output to be without the "www." part!

Comment: @SwakeertJain no, they very clearly do not. Look at their example of desired output, and it includes the strings with the `www.` prefix.

Comment: Sorry! my bad. I misunderstood the last statement in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strip` doesn't work that way. It will try to strip every single character of the passed argument, so possibly more than the string you passed. Also, you're sorting in-place, no need to return `None` (or use `sorted` which will sort a *copy* of your parameter, maybe less a surprise for callers)

You probably want `str.replace` instead to get rid of `www.`, or `re.sub("^www.","",x)`

```
def sort_it(lst, ignore):
  lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.replace(ignore,""))

myList = ["cheesewhiz", "www.cheese.com", "www.wagons.com", "www.apples.com", "www.bananas.com"]

ignoreThis = "www."
sort_it(myList, ignoreThis)
print(myList)
```

result:

```
['www.apples.com', 'www.bananas.com', 'www.cheese.com', 'cheesewhiz', 'www.wagons.com']
```

More accurately, if you want to remove `www.` from the key only if it starts with `www.` you could go with regex (although you'd need to escape the text):

```
import re

def sort_it(lst, ignore):
  lst.sort(key=lambda x: re.sub("^"+re.escape(ignore),"",x))
```

or without regex, maybe the best solution, with a ternary expression and `startswith` since we don't need regular expressions:

```
def sort_it(lst, ignore):
  lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[len(ignore):] if x.startswith(ignore) else x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Updated my code in the question to use the ignore parameter.